# search bar in sharepoint 2010.

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer

I am trying to have a search bar as a webpart on a site on the sharepoint wiki.

As I search it gives the results from the whole sharepoint, 
what I want to do is to restrict the search to a particular site on the sharepoint so that it gives the results pertaining only to that site and its pages rather than the whole intra wiki.

How can I do that.?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the properties/Query of the Search Result Web Part so that it only returns results (specified Content Types) from a defined address (Site/List/Library)